# Python try/pass during value assignment?

Tags: python, django, view, try-catch

**The situation:**
Django view fetches a data item from a server (Amazon's DynamoDB table), when a given HashKey is sent to the view via the url.

**The problem:**
Because it is a non-relational db, some items in the DynamoDB table are missing keys that other items may have --> A KeyError is raised for some of the fetching attempts, means that if I'm assigning a dictionary in the view it will stop the whole process because of that KeyError. This means I have to *try/except KeyError* for each fetch attempt (dictionary value assignment).

**The question:**
Is there a python syntax to allow a try/except on the same line while assigning a value? something like:

```
'times_a_day': try jsonFormatIndications[elem]['times_a_day']) except: pass
```

Thanks before!

Comment: Answer: no, there isn't. But you can e.g. `jsonFormatIndications.get(elem)...` (which will give `None` if the key `elem` is missing).

Comment: Wrap it up in a function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks man! This actually does the job for me. I wasn't aware of that syntax..

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, you can't do that in one line.**

**You can instead use [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) along with a function to handle all the cases gracefully in one line.**

> `get(key[, default])`
>   Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.

We can define a generic function named `get_nested_key_value()` which will take 3 arguments `my_dict`, `outer_key` and `inner_key` to fetch the required value.

`my_dict` : Dictionary on which lookup is being performed
`outer_key` : `elem` in this case
`inner_key` : The key being looked up in `elem` dictionary (`times_a_day` in this case)

We first check if `elem` is present in the dictionary and if it is present then check if `times_a_day` is present using `.get()`. If it is present, we will return the value. Otherwise, `None` is returned.

```
def get_nested_key_value(my_dict, outer_key, inner_key):
    if my_dict.get(outer_key) and my_dict[outer_key].get(inner_key): # check if both keys present
        return my_dict[outer_key][inner_key] # return the required value
    return None # return None if key not found
```

Then you can just call the function which will return the value in case key was found else `None`.

```
'times_a_day' : get_nested_key_value(jsonFormatIndications, elem, 'times_a_day')
```

Comment: Thanks. For now I'm doing .get on each line (double .get on double keys) but liked the idea